# DataStage Client (Designer) Crashes when I Try to Open "Configure"

Tags: datastage

I'm having a trouble whenever I try to open [Configure] of Unstructured Data stage in IBM Data Stage Designer. It is a client program on my machine.

[Unstructured Data Stage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DR0CD.png)

I have been searching the solution by googling for many days, but I couldn't figure out why it happens and how to fix it. Does anyone know about the issue and the solution?

I'm suffering from the issue because I have to work using Data Stage Designer. There is no error message and it just crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Unstructured Data stage needs flash. This also affects the Hierarchical Data stage. But [flash support has ended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/announcements/adobe-flash-end-of-support) and has been patched out of windows. To continue using Stages that need flash, you could use the Harnam flash plugin, which is not free.

The [official "solution"](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/hierarchical-data-stage-flash-player-end-support-dec-2020) suggests to either work with the Data Flow Designer, which does not need flash, or to install the Harnam Flash plugin.

Both solutions are controversially discussed, because the DFD has it's own issues and on the other hand re-introducing flash to the client machine undermines the security concept that has specifically banned flash from the system.

The plugin option seems to be more stable, though.

Oh, and last but not least some are already migrating to CP4D, which isn't an easy step for projects that evolved over decades, but could be the 3rd option.

Comment: Thank you so much Justus! I'm reading the official solution page. Hope I can use Data Stage in a stable mode. Thanks again.